# Grouping by fiscal year, and time conversion from seconds to dd,hh,mm,ss

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, type-conversion

I have a table with Columns "Fiscal Year (INT8)", "Month (text)", and "Time(in seconds, INT)
Example:

```
Fiscal Year    Month         Time
  2009        April       446613459
  2009        August      1148046955
  2009       December     2093891109    ...
```

I am trying to do two things.

1. I would like to convert the time (in seconds) which is showing the total amount of seconds each month that callers spent on hold - to display as something like "days, hours, minutes, seconds"
2. I will also need to provide a sum of the hold "time" per Fiscal Year, the data ranges from 2007-2022.  However, I need to group them by fiscal year with each year being from October 1 to September 30.

I'm fairly new to SQL and have been running into a lot of issues. Currently I am using postgres. Any help with this would be much appreciated!  Thank you!

Desired Outcome
Example Fiscal Year 2009 would be the sum of items for October 2008-September 2009.

```
Fiscal Year       Total Time
  2007           __days, __hours, __minutes, __seconds
  2008           __days, __hours, __minutes, __seconds
  2009           __days, __hours, __minutes, __seconds ...
```

Comment: you want to sum up the seconds and then convert it to day hours seconds?

Comment: it is quite hard to tell what time actually is, first i thought utc but the data doesn't fut with your year and moth and 446613459 is 5169 days, 3 hours, 17 minutes and 39 seconds. that is hardly in any fiscal year

Comment: Why don't you store the time as TIME (or TIMESTAMP when it also includes the date) ? 446613459 or so doesn't mean anything to a human being, it's just a large number.

Comment: I want to take the number of seconds that I have been given per month, and display that in an easier format such as days, hours. minutes, seconds  (I forgot to add in minutes in my initial post. sorry!   In the data set I have, the time listed (in seconds) is the total amount of time that calls spent prior to being answered by employees.  Hopefully this adds some clarity.

Comment: @FrankHeikens - the "time" field is the amount of time that callers spent in on hold.  It has been provided to me in total amount of seconds (and loaded as an integer) and I am trying to figure out how to display it in a more meaningful way i.e. days, hours, minutes, seconds

Comment: If that's the amount of seconds... You could use justify_interval: SELECT justify_interval(446613459 * INTERVAL '1 second' );

Answer (score 1):

Assume that values in `fiscal_year` and `month` are actually calendar year and month (ie. December 2009 is actually the 9th month of fiscal year 2009), then there're two calculations need to be done:

1. Convert `calendar year-month` to `fiscal year-month`;
2. Convert `time` (duration in seconds?) to days, hours, minutes and seconds

Such as:

```
fiscal_year|month    |calendar_month|fiscal_month|real_fiscal_year|time      |
-----------+---------+--------------+------------+----------------+----------+
       2008|September|    2008-09-01|  2008-06-01|          2008.0| 987654321|
       2008|October  |    2008-10-01|  2008-07-01|          2008.0| 123456789|
       2009|April    |    2009-04-01|  2009-01-01|          2009.0| 446613459|
       2009|August   |    2009-08-01|  2009-05-01|          2009.0|1148046955|
       2009|December |    2009-12-01|  2009-09-01|          2009.0|2093891109|
       2010|January  |    2010-01-01|  2009-10-01|          2009.0|1898989889|
       2010|March    |    2010-03-01|  2009-12-01|          2009.0| 300010001|
       2010|April    |    2010-04-01|  2010-01-01|          2010.0| 456785432|
```

Then the below query will do:

```
with cte as (
select cast(extract(year from to_date(fiscal_year || ' ' || month,'%Y MONTH') - '3 month'::interval) as int) as real_fiscal_year,
       sum(time) as time
  from fiscal_year_seconds
 group by 1)
select real_fiscal_year                    as fiscal_year,
       time / 86400                        as days,  
       mod(time, 86400)/3600               as hours,
       mod(mod(time, 86400), 3600)/60      as minutes,
       mod(mod(mod(time, 86400), 3600),60) as seconds
  from cte
 order by 1;
```

```
fiscal_year|days |hours|minutes|seconds|
-----------+-----+-----+-------+-------+
       2008|12860|    1|     58|     30|
       2009|68142|   22|     56|     53|
       2010| 5286|   20|     50|     32|
```

EDIT: Per request to put total time into a single column, we're going to need:

1. concatenate texts/strings together with `||` operator
2. `lpad()` to have fix length of days, hours, minutes and seconds
3. convert integer to characters with `::data_type` or `cast`

Here's an example:

```
with cte as (
select cast(extract(year from to_date(fiscal_year || ' ' || month,'%Y MONTH') - '3 month'::interval) as int) as real_fiscal_year,
       sum(time) as time
  from fiscal_year_seconds
 group by 1)
select real_fiscal_year as fiscal_year,
       lpad((time/86400)::char(10)                        , 10, ' ') || ' days '    ||  
       lpad((mod(time, 86400)/3600)::char(2)              ,  2, '0') || ' hours '   ||
       lpad((mod(mod(time, 86400), 3600)/60)::char(2)     ,  2, '0') || ' minutes ' ||
       lpad((mod(mod(mod(time, 86400), 3600),60))::char(2),  2, '0') || ' seconds ' as total_time
  from cte
 order by 1;
```

```
fiscal_year|total_time                                     |
-----------+-----------------------------------------------+
       2008|     12860 days 01 hours 58 minutes 30 seconds |
       2009|     68142 days 22 hours 56 minutes 53 seconds |
       2010|      5286 days 20 hours 50 minutes 32 seconds |
```

You may notice that `01 hours` should be `01 hour`. Either you can do `01 hour(s)` or utilize `case ... when ... else ...` conditional expression.

Comment: this was incredibly helpful.  Thank you!   Follow up question - is there a way to alter this where the converted seconds are displayed in a single column in a "dd:hh:mm:ss" format, or a single column that would read fpr example "5286 days, 20 hours, 50 minutes, 32 seconds"?